# Show a Label while AxAcroPDF is still rendering or loading a file

Tags: vb.net, axacropdf

Something like this

```
LoadingLabel.Visible = True
Me.AxAcroPDF1.setShowToolbar(False)
Me.AxAcroPDF1.LoadFile(MyFileToLoad)
LoadingLabelVisible = False
```

is not working, the `LoadingLabelVisible = False` is executed even when the file still is rendering or loading or with a blank page

I don´t find a property on the AxAcroPDF1, something like "Loaded", "Busy"...

Is there a way to make this work? With a thread by example?

Comment: is there an event available which fires when it has completed?

Comment: Nothing you can do with that miserable control.  Add LoadingLabel.Update() so you can actually see the label.

Comment: @Plutonix I didn't find one, but maybe I'm wrong

Comment: @HansPassant Add LoadingLabel.Update()  after the "Me.AxAcroPDF1.LoadFile(MyFileToLoad)" line?